# RedBean simple model

Tags: php, mysql, orm, redbean

I've been told to use some ORM library to make storage easier.
I've read about Doctrine, RedBeans and some other ones. I'm giving RedBeans a try because it's quite simple and requires no configuration.
I already tried some basic code to store beans and so.

If I want to have a model class (a bean?), to add some basic behaviour and functions.
What class do I need to extend? What methods do I need to override and then how should I get an instance of them?

Example: a Blog class which contains a User and Posts

Comment: Also my favorite! Currently looking fpr C++ port of it.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to my question was a feature of RedBean called 'Fuse'.
It was as simple as extending RedBean_SimpleModel class and implementing delete and update methods.
The downside of RedBean is the lack of tutorials/documentations (their wiki is really poor)